# HTML, how to pass textbox variable to xml src?

Tags: html, xml

I can manually put user id U078058 in xml src and get his phone number display,

```
   <xml id="XmlUserInfo2" src="http://{ServerName}/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=U078058"> </xml>
<p>
    phone number: <span datasrc="#XmlUserInfo2" datafld="telephoneNumber" dataformatas="html"></span>
</p>
```

Now instead of manually put user id in xml src, I want to pass user id from textbox to xml src.
Will this work?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textUID" runat="Server">U078058</asp:TextBox>

<xml id="XmlUserInfo2" src="http://{ServerName}/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=textUID"> </xml>
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript.

Comment: Can you provide an example for javascript?

Comment: First you have to show your ACTUAL HTML, not your server-side code.